# Can the MAPI is disabled in Outlook 365?

Tags: security, mapi, o365security-compliance

I just wanted to know if I can disable MAPI in outlook 365 in order to prevent the cyber attack using ruler/MAPI? If I disable the MAPI, will the clients email flows be affected ? or Is there any business impact if I disable the MAPI?

Also, some sort of suggestions to prevent the ruler/MAPI attack would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Praba

Answer (score 0):

No, MAPI is the native API for Outlook. It cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is built on top of Extended MAPI subsystems and if you disable them you will not be able to use Outlook at all. It is like if you disable Windows API - any application will not be run on Windows.